# (500) Internal Server Error - When sending web request using api

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebrequest

I am sending a web request and getting internal server error : 500.

How can i be sure what side is responsible for getting this error?
My side or the external api side?

I didn`t see logs in my event viewer.

This is my code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://saas.appoxee.com/api/") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

// Add the content to the request
string postDataJsonFormat = CreateExampleTagRequest();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postDataJsonFormat);
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

// Getting and processing the response
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"**500.0 – Internal Server Error**" is an IIS Error code meaning that the web service is unavailable. This means the error is with the API, not your client.

**Summary of server codes:**

> 1xx - Informational
>
> 2xx - Success
>
> 3xx - Redirection
>
> 4xx - Client error
>
> 5xx - Server error

For a full list of codes look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891
and about the **500** code specifically: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942031

Comment: Sometimes you could get a 500 error if you don't make your request properly.