# Getting an "Internal Server Error" when trying to post messages in Microsoft Bot Connector by Direct Line API

Tags: c#, botframework

I've set up a simple bot - registered with Bot Connector - and I'm just trying to get the basic Direct Line API connection set up.  In my separate application (C#), I've succeeded at *initiating* a conversation by using an HttpClient and retrieving the conversationId (by deserializing the response).

However, I then attempt to post a message to the thread, and I'm getting a "Internal Server Error", error code 500.  The only message attached is "An error has occurred.".

```
using(var client =  new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"BotConnector {token}");
client.DefaultRequestheaders.Add("Type", "Message");
var post_content = new StringContent("Adding to the convo", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = new client.PostAsync($"api/conversations/{convo_id}/messages", post_content).Result;
log(response.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

log is a simple method to output to the console, while convo_id is the conversationId taken from the initial call to the site.

Comment: Have you posted the full error? This answer suggests there should be a number associated with it, maybe that could help find the anwer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713666/500-internal-server-error-when-sending-web-request-using-api

Comment: Edited to respond: it's a simple 500 error.  That's the confusion: there's no details provided by the Bot Connector API to explain what's going awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code:

```
var post_content = new StringContent("Adding to the convo", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

is the source of the problems.
Look at the format of the message expected:
http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#!/Conversations/Conversations_PostMessage

It's expecting a JSON object with a bunch of fields. I was able to repo your problem and changed the content of the message and the error goes away.

```
Message message = new Message(conversationId: convId, text: "Happy days");
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
var post_content = new StringContent(output,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
```

Comment: An excellent catch! Thanks for the help!  In the meantime I've switched to using the NuGet package identified by your first answer, but I'm glad to be able to understand the full situation.  I hope the documentation gets a bit clearer soon, but your insight here was quite valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine NuGet package, I'm having some success with the DirectLine API.

```
var uri = new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com");

DirectLineClientCredentials creds = new DirectLineClientCredentials(secret);

DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(uri, creds);
Conversations convs = new Conversations(client);

string waterMark;

var conv = convs.NewConversation();
var set = convs.GetMessages(conv.ConversationId);
waterMark = set.Watermark;

Message message = new Message(conversationId: conv.ConversationId, text: "your text");
Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
convs.PostMessage(conv.ConversationId, message);

set = convs.GetMessages(conv.ConversationId, waterMark);
PrintResponse(set);
waterMark = set.Watermark;
```

with the PrintResponse defined as:

```
private static void PrintResponse(MessageSet set)
{
  var q = from x in set.Messages
          where x.FromProperty == "<YOUR BOTS APP ID HERE>"
          select x.Text;

  foreach (var str in q.ToList())
   {
      Console.WriteLine(">> " +str);
   }


}
```

Comment: Yeah I found that package...frustrating that it's entirely undocumented as far as I can tell.  But this doesn't unfortunately address the question of why the simple REST command is failing.